# LDPC codes general question

Tags: coding-theory

Today I was reading wireless communication book chapter about coding. I have little knowledge in coding. So I ask for help in the following paragraph.

**For the encoding, a low-density parity check coder is used. It always uses a codeword of length of 672 bits and the coding rate varies. The 3/4 matrix with shortening is used here, which results in a code rate of 1/2 or less**

Can somebody help me understand this part of coding? I need a brief help and I will take the explanation and put effort on my own thanks.

Comment: That does not compute. When we shorten a code, the length of codewords changes. It get shortened (surprise!) and cannot stay at 672 bits. I suspect that something else is meant, but cannot make an educated guess with this scant data. Usually shortening a code means that we use systematic encoding, set some subset of payload bits to zero, and then decide not to transmit those "known" zeros (and consequently shorten the block length).

Comment: I think the shortening in this case is puncturing, e.g. if you have a  systematic encoder, you encode as normal and then throw away some of the parity bits.